# lifetime error with actix and tokio_postgres

Tags: rust

I am trying to write an auth server by using `actix` and `tokio_postgres` in a way like [FrameworkBenchmarks](https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/0e0a0e5edbfc3064fd623f587bb96003776a745c/frameworks/Rust/actix/src/db_pg.rs) did, my code is like:

```rust
use tokio_postgres::{Client, Statement, NoTls, connect};
use actix::{Actor, Context, Addr, Message, Handler, ResponseFuture};
use std::io;
use futures::future::FutureExt;

pub struct PgConnection {
    client: Client,
    login: Statement,
}

impl Actor for PgConnection {
    type Context = Context<Self>;
}

impl PgConnection {
    pub async fn connect(db_url: &str) -> Result<Addr<PgConnection>, io::Error> {
        let (cl, conn) = connect(db_url, NoTls)
            .await
            .expect("can not connect to postgresql");
        actix_rt::spawn(conn.map(|_| ()));

        let login = cl.prepare("SELECT id FROM User_ WHERE username='$1' AND password=crypt($2, gen_salt('bf'))").await.unwrap();

        Ok(PgConnection::create(move |_| PgConnection {
            client: cl,
            login,
        }))
    }
}

pub struct LoginRequest;

impl Message for LoginRequest {
    type Result = io::Result<String>;
}

impl Handler<LoginRequest> for PgConnection {
    type Result = ResponseFuture<Result<String, io::Error>>;

    fn handle(&mut self, _: LoginRequest, _: &mut Self::Context) -> Self::Result {
        let fut = self.client
            .query_one(&self.login, &[&"1", &"2"]);

        Box::pin(async move {
            let row = fut
                .await
                .map_err(|e| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, format!("{:?}", e)))?;

            Ok(row.get(0))
        })
    }
}
```

But I met up with a confusing lifetime error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/db.rs:44:14
   |
44 |             .query_one(&self.login, &[&"1", &"2"]);
   |              ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 42:5...
  --> src/db.rs:42:5
   |
42 | /     fn handle(&mut self, _: LoginRequest, _: &mut Self::Context) -> Self::Result {
43 | |         let fut = self.client
44 | |             .query_one(&self.login, &[&"1", &"2"]);
45 | |
...  |
52 | |         })
53 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/db.rs:43:19
   |
43 |         let fut = self.client
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/db.rs:46:9
   |
46 | /         Box::pin(async move {
47 | |             let row = fut
48 | |                 .await
49 | |                 .map_err(|e| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, format!("{:?}", e)))?;
50 | |
51 | |             Ok(row.get(0))
52 | |         })
   | |__________^
   = note: expected  `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>> + 'static)>>`
              found  `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<dyn core::future::future::Future<Output = std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>>>>`
```

Can anybody tell me what the problem is and how can I fix it?

Just in case, my dependency versions:

```
[dependencies]
tokio-postgres = "0.5.4"
actix-web = "2.0.0"
actix-rt = "1.1.1"
actix = "0.9.0"
futures = "0.3.4"
```

And my cargo and rustc version : 
cargo 1.43.0 (3532cf738 2020-03-17)
rustc 1.43.0 (4fb7144ed 2020-04-20)

Comment: I think it's because of the benchmark use a different version of tokio_postgres.

https://github.com/fafhrd91/rust-postgres.git